# UIImageView animation And UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview, uikit

I am running two animations at the same time and getting unexpected results.

I have an animation that is a series of .pngs in a `UIImage`setup like this...

```
func animateImages(duration: NSTimeInterval) -> Void {

    loadingView.animationImages = loadingAnimatedImages
    loadingView.animationDuration = duration
    loadingView.animationRepeatCount = 0
    loadingView.hidden = false
    loadingView.startAnimating()
}
```

and then an animation that uses `UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration` set up like this...

```
func animateView(duration: NSTimeInterval) -> Void {
    circle.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = animationCircleView.frame.size.width/2
    circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    animationCircleView.addSubview(circle)
    circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)

    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: .CalculationModeLinear, animations: { 
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: .33, animations: { 
            self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
            self.circle.alpha = 1.0
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(.33, relativeDuration: .33, animations: { 
            self.circle.alpha = 0.5
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(.66, relativeDuration: .33, animations: { 
             self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
        })

        }) { (success) in
             animationCircleView.hidden = true
    }
}
```

and then they are called in the same method..

```
func animate() -> Void {
   animateView(2.0)
   animateImages(2.0)
}
```

Both animations run, the image animation always runs fine, but the UIView animation always runs on a delay.  I'm thinking its something to do with a main thread lock, but not certain.

Does anyone know of a solution?  work around?  switch to drawRect of the UIView animation instead of animation?

any thoughts appreciated!